# How to run a flux query based on the result of another flux query

Tags: influxdb, flux

I'm trying to use the output of a query in another query.

This is the code I have. Its not complete and I'd like to use other columns from the function, but cannot get past this point:

```
ExchDates = from(bucket: "priceData")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Prices")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "PriceA")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_value"] > 15)
|> group(columns: ["ExchDate"])
|> first()
|> drop(columns:["_value","_measurement", "_field", "_start", "_stop", "_time"])

from(bucket: "priceData")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["ExchDate"] == ExchDates.ExchDate)
```

I get an error:

```
error @12:38-12:46: expected {A with _value: B} (record) but found stream[C]
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?